# How does Windows calculate alias names for certificates exported into PFX files?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, pki

I have an app which imports one certificate stored in a PFX file and requires users to provide the alias of the one and only certificate to import. Some users maintain their certificates using the Windows cert store and export them from there into PFX files and want to upload those files into my app in the end. Certs are exported either manually using `certmgr.msc` or e.g. using some Powershell script using [Export-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-pfxcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

The problem is that alias names generated in both ways seem to be unpredictable GUIDs or something. Though, when exporting the same certificate over and over again, the alias name is stable and doesn't seem to change at all. OTOH, it doesn't seem to be that easy to apply some alias name in the cert store and export using that, Windows still generates something looking like a GUID. Additionally, I don't see any argument to [Export-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-pfxcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to specify a custom alias name.

```
C:\Users\tschoening>keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore Desktop\tschoening_ps.pfx
Keystore-Kennwort eingeben:
Keystore-Typ: PKCS12
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore enthält 1 Eintrag

Aliasname: 2fb763d2-f1fa-4820-8caf-f73e011ee4d1
```

For different tested certificates the alias even looks slightly different:

```
Aliasname: {a16a26b0-7d2e-4366-95b9-40f06b45b578}
```

`certutil` provides similar output:

```
C:\Users\tschoening>certutil -v -dumpPFX Desktop\tschoening.pfx
[...]
  Attribut[1]: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.20 (szOID_PKCS_12_FRIENDLY_NAME_ATTR)
    Wert [1][0], Länge = 4a
    CryptFormatObject: Keine integrierte Formatierungshilfe
    2fb763d2-f1fa-4820-8caf-f73e011ee4d1
    0000  1e 48 00 32 00 66 00 62  00 37 00 36 00 33 00 64   .H.2.f.b.7.6.3.d
    0010  00 32 00 2d 00 66 00 31  00 66 00 61 00 2d 00 34   .2.-.f.1.f.a.-.4
    0020  00 38 00 32 00 30 00 2d  00 38 00 63 00 61 00 66   .8.2.0.-.8.c.a.f
    0030  00 2d 00 66 00 37 00 33  00 65 00 30 00 31 00 31   .-.f.7.3.e.0.1.1
    0040  00 65 00 65 00 34 00 64  00 31                     .e.e.4.d.1
0000: 1e 48                                     ; UNICODE_STRING (48 Bytes)
0002:    00 32 00 66 00 62 00 37  00 36 00 33 00 64 00 32  ; .2.f.b.7.6.3.d.2
0012:    00 2d 00 66 00 31 00 66  00 61 00 2d 00 34 00 38  ; .-.f.1.f.a.-.4.8
0022:    00 32 00 30 00 2d 00 38  00 63 00 61 00 66 00 2d  ; .2.0.-.8.c.a.f.-
0032:    00 66 00 37 00 33 00 65  00 30 00 31 00 31 00 65  ; .f.7.3.e.0.1.1.e
0042:    00 65 00 34 00 64 00 31                           ; .e.4.d.1
            ; "2fb763d2-f1fa-4820-8caf-f73e011ee4d1"
```

**So, how does Windows calculate that alias? Is there any way to provide a custom alias during export?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias is generated from the key's unique identifier:

```
$CertObject = Get-ChildItem .\13CEF3D48F1287173401CE1B189C161F46585F1F
$rsaCert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($CertObject)
$rsaCert.key.KeyName
{6E9844BC-51A1-408E-A421-2D53B253C8B4}
```

Obviously, the values will be different for you.

As far as I know, the only way to change it would be to use some third-party tool such as OpenSSL.

Comment: So the key's unique identifier is the value of `key.KeyName` and that 1:1 used as alias in the PFX? Looks to me like that for my certificate and PFX as well. Do you know how that `KeyName` is generated?

Comment: Sadly, Microsoft don't say much about how `keyName` is generated.  It is also read-only, so it can't be changed to something more user friendly before export.  It looks just like a GUID to me.

Comment: The key name is chosen by the creator of the key when they create it.  PFX import uses the exported name if it has one and the name isn't taken... or a GUID if it has to make one up.  Since everyone naming a key "encryption key" makes for a lot of conflict, the OS core crypto team generally recommends all keys be named GUIDs (based on a discussion I had with one of them a couple of years ago).